# ABCpdf PdfConformityOperation.GetData PDFException

Tags: abcpdf

Occasionally, (ABCpdf 11) PdfConformityOperation.GetData throws a PDFException like this:

> WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.Internal.PDFException: Unable to serialize PDF.
> bad conversion. bei   .(   ,  ) bei WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.Doc.(
> ) bei
> WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.Operations.PdfConformityOperation.GetData(Doc
> doc)

This is admittedly only very minimal information, and certainly not enough to investigate the matter, so please be lenient with me about this question.

Did anyone else have such or similar exceptions from PdfConformityOperation.GetData and found a way to circumvent them?

Thanks a lot for any hints! :)

[image]